# Rails 4 Bootstrap 3.3, media queries causing error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, media-queries, multiple-columns

I am a newb, but I'm trying something that I think should be easy, but I'm getting a rails server error.  I want my text to break into columns for larger devices.

I have in my html:

```
<div class="col">
        <p>
            Ricter Web Printing...
        </p>    
</div>
```

my css.scss has:

```
.col {
@media (min-width: @screen-hs-min) {
   /* rules for mobile horizontal (480 > 768)  */
    -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
   /* rules for tablet (768 > 992) */
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
   /* rules for desktop (992 > 1200) */
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
   /* rules for large (> 1200) */
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

The columns work fine with no media query.  The media query is copied and pasted right from the bootstrap site.  Other bootstrap is working perfectly including a responsive nav...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Providing the content of the error is always helpful. Also it looks like you are missing the final `}` in the code you posted. Is that missing in your actual code? That would cause an error.

Comment: Unfortunately the final } is there, that would have been an easy fix.  The error is as follows: 

ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...ia (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@screen-hs-min) {"
  (in /Users/timbillington/New_Ricter_Site/RicterSite/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:55)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>RicterSite</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
...

Comment: Okay, it is a typo. `@screen-hs-min` should probably be `@screen-xs-min`.

Comment: I tried switching the hs for xs, still gives the error.  See my answer below for what I ended up with.

Answer (score 3):

I have it working, still not sure why my first code didn't work, but I tried this version and it is perfect:

```
.col {
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

}

I might play with my column numbers and break points, but it is functionally perfect.  Hope that helps someone else...