# Bootstrap Media Queries Rails Error

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the font on my app larger for small devices by overriding bootstrap media queries.

I am trying to do it like this, by setting the font size for h1's using bootstrap media queries

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  h1{font-size: 5rem}
}
```

only I get this Rails error message.

```
Invalid CSS after "...ia (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@screen-sm-min) {"
```

I see in the below answer they are overriding by explicitly stating the width, which doesn't throw the error anymore for me, but I'm not sure why I can't use bootstraps variables. Do I have to set the value of @screen-sm-min somewhere in order to use it?

[Rails 4 Bootstrap 3.3, media queries causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224728/rails-4-bootstrap-3-3-media-queries-causing-error)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this number explains what was going on on the bootstrap migrating to bootstrap 4 website:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

`All @screen- variables have been removed in v4.0.0. Use the media-breakpoint-up(), media-breakpoint-down(), or media-breakpoint-only() Sass mixins or the $grid-breakpoints Sass map instead.`

If you're using sass you can do something like this for small devices:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
  strong {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}
```

But I ended up ultimately setting the values:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  strong {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The media query should say:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}
```

variables in css start with a dollar sign. Assuming the variable is actually called `screen-sm-min`, you should be good. You also forgot the semi-colon after `font-size: 5rem` just FYI